# Failed to enable unit: File log.service: No such file or directory

Tags: runlevel

I want to log something before shutdown or poweroff.

```
uname -a
Linux xxx 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.51-1 (2017-09-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux

systemctl get-default
graphical.target
runlevel
N 5
```

To edit my script.

```
sudo vim   /etc/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants/log.service
[Unit]
Description=Run command at shutdown
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/log.sh
```

To enable it.

```
sudo systemctl  enable  log.service
Failed to enable unit: File log.service: No such file or directory
```

How to fix it? 
What is the matter with the following setting?

```
sudo cat   /etc/systemd/system/log.service
[Unit]
Description=Run command at shutdown
After=shutdown.target reboot.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/log.sh


[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Enable it with `sudo systemctl  enable  log.service` without any issue.
Why no log info ,the `/home/log.sh`  can't execute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not create units in the `graphical.target.wants` directory, that directory is meant for symlinks. Instead, create it directly in the `/etc/systemd/system` directory.

Furthermore, you want to have an `[Install]` section, describing where to install it when the `systemctl enable` command is used. (In your case, you could use `graphical.target`, though `multi-user.target` is a more common choice and it's a dependency of `graphical.target`, so it will be pulled during boot.)

So create this under `/etc/systemd/system/log.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=...

[Service]
...
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/log.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then enable it with:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable log.service
```

This should work then.

It is possible that your dependencies are incorrect. You have `Before=shutdown.target reboot.target`, but most likely you need to use an `After=` dependency for services that you need to run *before* they are stopped. Dependencies work in an inverse order on shutdown, so list the ones you depend (such as `local-fs.target`, `network.target`) in that `After=` clause. The `RequiresMountsFor=` directive might also be interesting, for filesystems that you need mounted for your log.sh to be able to run...

Comment: Why no log info ,the /home/log.sh can't execute?